# 1 000 000 человек в месяц!

Tags: обсуждение, вехи

Коллеги, мы взяли новый рубеж популярности нашей базы знаний! Аудитория Stack Overflow на русском в месяц достигла 1 миллиона человек!

[image: 1 000 000]

Спасибо каждому, кто задает вопросы и отвечает на них. Результат нашей совместной работы очень важен и нужен миллиону коллег в месяц!

Comment: Уиии, ЧСВ погладил!

Comment: Хорошая новость. А сколько составляет доля посетителей из России? Половина? 80%

Comment: @AK Первая пятерка: РФ — 62%, Украина — 21%, РБ — 6%, Казахстан — 3%, США — 1%. Интересно, что Украина по населению в три раза меньше РФ, что говорит об одинаковом интересе среди граждан стран в процентном соотношении. РБ в 15 раз меньше РФ по населению, Казахстан в 8. Пятерка городов: Москва, Киев, Санкт–Петербург, Минск, Харьков.

Comment: По поводу Казахстана - сектор ИТ не так сильно развит у нас, как в РФ и на Украине, так что 3% для нас уже что-то))

Comment: @DaemonHK Если смотреть на цифры, то можно предположить, что самые хорошие условия для программистов в РБ!

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky это откуда такие выводы?)) Все же из ЗП вытекает

Comment: @DaemonHK В РБ население в 9 млн, в РФ — 146 млн. При этом, РБ —
 6%, а РФ — 62%. То есть, количество посетителей сайта (потенциальных разработчиков) к населению в РБ на треть больше, чем в РФ.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, так у нас в РК, как и в РБ, одинаковые условия, то же кол-во "разработчиков" получается))

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky немало моих бывших коллег уехали в РБ и утверждают, что там вообще хорошо, а программисту особенно :)

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev занятно. Если РБ - это Беларусь, то у меня прямо противоположный опыт общения с сотрудниками IT сектора из Беларуси )

Comment: @Suvitruf возможно, что это связано с тем, из какого региона нашей необъятной они переехали. Возможность не убегать от медведей по глубокому снегу может очень радовать!

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Минск и Бобруйск.

Comment: `Avg. Session Duration` -- в каких единицах? Интересно, процент ботов по ней можно оценить?

Comment: @avp Это данные в секундах.

Comment: Тогда людей намного меньше миллиона.

Comment: @avp Поясните, пожалуйста, вашу мысль.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, 1000000 -- это (к сожалению) не число людей, посетивших нас. Судя по средней продолжительности в 2 секунды большинство соединений от каких-то ботов (м.б. поисковики или что-то еще).

Comment: @avp Видимо, я не верно понял ваш вопрос. Среднее время - 2 минуты 34 секунды, если я правильно понимаю.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, ага, 2 минуты это уже другое дело. За пару минут можно осознать, набрел ты на интересующий ответ или надо серфить дальше

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky а Витебск(РБ) есть? На каком месте?

Comment: Молодцы!!! Оличнейший, знаковый, сакральный результат! )

Comment: А где такую статистику можно самому посмотреть? Интересует на сколько близко в плане популярности toster.ru ([Статистика Тостера за 2017 год](https://habr.com/company/toster/blog/347028/)).

Comment: А как с этим в 2019?