# Неофициальная встреча в Москве/Санкт-Петербурге

Tags: обсуждение, встречи-сообщества

Хотелось бы встречу провести. Нужно определиться с городом и форматом заодно.

Для начала, хочется понять, в каком городе участники могут прийти. Пока такую форму предлагаю заполнить https://goo.gl/DsYr5e, чтоб хотя бы понять, где большинство обитает.

Если есть предложения, пишите (:

**UPD:** [обсуждение дат и места встречи](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8841/15479).

Comment: Отличная идея! Спасибо! Пожалуйста, обратите внимание: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4858/6

Comment: Поставил  Москву т.к. хоть иногда туда заезжаю :D

Comment: А по датам что-нибудь есть, хотя бы с точностью до месяца?

Comment: @AnT сложно сказать. Я бы ориентировался на конец Марта - начало Апреля.

Comment: @Suvitruf Ок. Я с 3 по 24 марта в Минске. Мог бы и сгонять в Москву в рамках отпускной программы...

Comment: @AnT учту, когда будем с датами определяться (:

Comment: Встречу нужно организовать в поезде Калининград-Владивосток.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov в Июле )

Comment: Что, значит в Украине таких мероприятий не будет? А жаль. Думаю в Украине тоже есть участники SO.

Comment: @Aqua так если хотите, запилите тему )

Comment: @Suvitruf просто насколько я знаю уже будет вторая встреча за моё присутствие в SO. Нужно будет найти время...

Comment: @Aqua Киев — второй по популярности город среди посетителей Stack Overflow на русском. Я очень хотел организовать встречу, но к сожалению, как я понял, сейчас до Киева довольно сложно добраться по юридическим причинам.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky а первое и третье места у кого?

Comment: @AntonSorokin [На сколько помню](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7121/1-000-000-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BA-%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8F%D1%86#comment28475_7121), Москва и Санкт-Петербург, затем идет Минск.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky (тут я кое что удалил и я забыл начальное сообщение)
 посмотрел сообщение по ссылке, все понял, спасибо.

Comment: На будущее предлагаю формат встречи для СПб - собраться где нибудь у невского проспекта(или у другого красивого места), в субботу в 15-**16**-17 часов, погулять, потом переместится в кафе. Или у памятника какого-то(такие сходки часто устраивают разные ютюб деятели со своими подписчиками). В апреле-мае(в марте еще холодно).

Comment: @AntonSorokin в кафе всем места может не хватить. Нужно заранее забивать)

Comment: @Suvitruf так можно и зарезервировать. Можно зарезервировать какую нибудь кафешку-бар,  допустим если бронируем на 17-17.30 встречаемся в 16, гуляем до 17-17.30(разброс пол часа, т.к. вдруг всем понравится, красиво хорошо и т.д.), приходим в кафе.

Comment: кто за это чудо платит?

Comment: @michael_best за что именно? о_О

Comment: @michael_best Администрация **не** платит. В кафе - каждый сам за себя. Почему "чудо"?

Comment: + за Москву. Собираться надо в баре, каждый платит за себя. Бар должен быть в центре. Если собираться в пятницу, стол надо заказать заранее. Мы клубом программистов на новый год собирались в Козловне на Мясницкой, рядом Лубянка, Китай-город, Кузнецкий мост, Сретенский бульвар. Пиво фирменное 250 за 0,5 — хорошее.

Comment: Я за встречу днём а не вечером, так как из подмосковья и вечером высоковероятно не смогу, так как ехать долго. Можно на выходных.