# Место и время неофициальной встречи в Москве

Tags: обсуждение, встречи-сообщества

80% голосов по теме "[Неофициальная встреча в Москве/Санкт-Петербурге](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8798/15479)" было за Москву. Так что, город встречи определён (но ничто не мешает кому-то другому провести встречу в Питере). По голосованию большинство было за бар/кафешку.

По поводу дат, предполагаю, что встреча будет ближе к середине/концу Марта, но это обсуждаемо. Многие в силу работы и других причин не могут посреди недели на встречу прийти. Так что, как мне кажется, логично выбирать между пятницей, субботой, воскресеньем. В голосовании добавил даты: 15-17 Марта, 22-24 Марта.

Ну и следует определиться окончательно с местом. В ответах можете делиться идеями. Если есть у кого-то на примете уютное местечко, где не слишком шумно, предлагайте также в ответах. А то я хиккан, особо мест irl не знаю.

Пока такой опросик накидал: https://goo.gl/bggxH6. Телефон опционален.

**UPD:** по текущим голосам пока лидируют пятница/суббота в 19/20:00

Comment: Проголосовал за любое место в центре Москвы (одна-две остановки максимум от малой кольцевой линии метро, ну и чтобы от метро идти не более 10 минут), конкретное место в принципе не особо критично.

Comment: Помню как то были в ШтирБирЛиц на ВДНХ, там есть отдельный зал со столом человек на 15, отделенный от остального заведения. Конечно надо уточнять что у них там сейчас.

Comment: В прошлый раз встречались в Старина Мюллер на Рождественском б-ре, там был длинный стол, а сейчас смотрю гугл, а бара-то там уже нет. Посмотрел фотки аналога на Бауманской, похоже человек 12-15 они могут разместить, но видимо надо заранее бронировать

Comment: В Ян Примусе на Бауманской бывали большими компаниями и сколько раз там бывал - народу было мало (хотя не помню, был ли я там в пятницу).

Comment: Эх, проворонила за Питер проголосовать!

Comment: @kizoso ничего, мы все равно в чате [обсуждали](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/49149745#49149745) сходку в питере, где-то в апреле-мае

Comment: Чуть не прозевал такое событие...

Comment: если для кого-то не слишком значимо и он выбрал 15-17, то прошу переголосовать за 22-24 (сами мы не местные и понаедем как раз к 22 марта)

Comment: Какая-то определенность по поводу даты, времени и места появилась?

Comment: @Suvitruf Пора окончательно определиться, а то придется новое голосование устраивать. Да и место надо уже думаю резервировать. Хотя такие вещи может быть лучше более чем за неделю делать.

Comment: @Mike https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8861/15479

Comment: @rdorn 22 Марта https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8861/15479