# Неофициальная встреча в Москве 22 Марта в 19:00

Tags: обсуждение, встречи-сообщества

- [Неофициальная встреча в Москве/Санкт-Петербурге](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8798/15479).
- [Место и время неофициальной встречи в Москве](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8841/15479).

По голосам лидирует **22 Марта**. По времени большинство за **19:00**, на втором месте 20:00. Думаю, если начнём собираться в **19:00**, то в 20:00 как раз подтянутся все.

По поводу места, было 50/50 за бар/кафе. Если половина не пьёт, то, думаю, лучше собраться в кафе. Но вообще, из предложений:

- [БирХаус](http://www.beerbar.ru/about/#prospektmira).
- [Вареничная №1 на Третьяковской](http://varenichnaya.ru/varenichnaya-1-tretyakovskaya/) (тут я периодически бываю; весьма неплохое место на покушать и поговорить).
- [Антикафе чекпоинт](https://chpoint.ru/).
- [Паб St. Peters & St. Anton](http://www.realpub.ru).

Пару дней ещё собираю предложения по месту. Во вторник окончательно определимся.

**UPD:**

1. [Не робот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/196/not-a-robot) за эту встречу не выдадут, т.к. не будет представителя компании.
2. Атрибутики не будет, т.к. SO запрещает печатать оную на стороне.

**UPD2:** встреча будет в [Пабе St.Peters & St.Anton](http://www.realpub.ru/). Забронировал на 10 человек. Станция метро "Охотный ряд". Предлагаю собираться на улице недалеко от входа.

**UPD3:** для связи со мной, [VK](https://vk.com/suvitruf), [Телеграм](https://telegram.me/Suvitruf).

**UPD4:** собираемся где-то тут:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вродеж только только былажеж?

Comment: @Grundy в Москве? Когда? О_о

Comment: встреча :-) недавно :-)

Comment: а где собираются предложения? я за антикафе если что

Comment: @Anatol можно тут, можно ответом оформить и расписать поподробнее)

Comment: @Anatol в антикафе еды нет, только снеки. Многие с работы идут, для них не очень вариант. А доставку ждать - ну, такое.

Comment: @Grundy: Это была поддельная, несанкционированная неофициальная встреча: вроде все на месте, а радости от нее - никакой.

Comment: а плашку за это можно будет получить?:)

Comment: @Vyacheslav я надеюсь, что да (:

Comment: @Suvitruf а кто этим будет заниматься?:)

Comment: @Vyacheslav я уточню этот вопрос.

Comment: Так встреча уже закончилась?

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин нет, с чего это?

Comment: @Suvitruf подумалось из комментариев.

Comment: Если вечер будет я не думаю что смогу, я в подмосковье живу, ехать далеко. Возможно есть варианты на выходных?

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин к сожалению, большинство за пятницу. Видимо, на выходных более важные дела есть )

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин такси?

Comment: Ну если в пятницу, то хотя бы пораньше, может будут желающие, а остальные могут и позже подойти...

Comment: Не знаю где тут голосовать, но я не пью и за безалкогольное место.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин я сам на работе обычно до 7. И то, что собираемся в 7, для меня тоже не очень удобно. Но позже будет ещё хуже.

Comment: Все варианты выглядят интересно (разве что Вареничная немного выбивается по стилю). Планирую быть даже пораньше 19

Comment: А есть ограничения по репутации? Или всем желающим можно прийти?

Comment: @YuryBakharev все желающие могут прийти )

Comment: _"Атрибутики не будет, т.к. SO запрещает печатать оную на стороне."_ - разве?

Comment: @Qwertiy мне так Николас сказал. Я просил сорсы, чтоб самому принты на футболки сделать.

Comment: @Suvitruf так можно самому нарисовать(если уж дико хочется), есть же сайты которые берут на заказ любые рисунки не так уж дорого(рекламу видел). Конечно, если администрация SE ни в какую не хочет давать сорцы для печатанья атрибутики(если уж они не могут/хотят отправить футболки в обход)) Николаса)  самостоятельно - то это уже какой то бред. Кстати, как вам маечка? https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFlcK.png (связана с теслами(S3XY) если что)

Comment: Надо в это же время провести официальную с нероботами и атрибутиками в СПб :)

Comment: Паб в результате выбрали. Ладно, ребята, успешной встречи! Для меня отсутствие выпивки важно, так как вообще не пью и не пил, и находится в поле алкоголя для мне неприятно и не подходит вообще. Думал выберете неалкогольное место...

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин не думаю, что там кто-то планирует напиваться. Но, ваш выбор. В следующий раз тогда )

Comment: Да, я понимаю, и без обиды. Просто для меня это реально не подходит. И понимаю что именно наша тусовка врядли бы сильно стала пить, но там могут быть и другие люди...

Comment: из-за алкашки я тоже пока под вопросом

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин  Да ладно вам, что вы из за паба сразу отказываетесь. Я тоже категорически против алкоголя(и грустно видеть что для многих людей для хорошей встречи/веселья/и т.п. нужен алкоголь), но я бы пришел если бы был в мск и по времени подходило, потому что я  уверен, что там никто не будет  "набухиваться", да и вообще налегать на алкоголь. Так что мне кажется что если вы не придете то вы очень многое потеряете.  тем более, вас же никто не заставляет там пить, и не-пья вы покажете остальным, что отлично провести время можно и без спиртного.

Comment: Жаль, конечно, что такая принципиальность (с куревом было бы понятно - дым, запах, а тут то что ..), но дело ваше. В защиту выбора и любителей пабов, скажу, что наоборот рад, что паб выбрали, т.к. там атмосфера веселее, и еда поинтереснее ;-P

Comment: можно вопрос не по теме ??? средний "уровень " в балах на "таких" встречах какой ??? бывают ли на таких встречах люди с 100 балами, либо только люди от 2 000 балов ?

Comment: @timob256 я ни разу не был на встречал SO irl )

Comment: @Suvitruf я бы пришёл, но как вспомню что у меня "маленький"и короткий", а у всех на встрече будет "большой и длинный " (я про количество баллов). ТО в таких случаях я не чувствую себя мужчиной. А если ещё своими результатами начнут "махать" то я получу dizable of morale и начнётся отступление юнита (то бишь меня ). Потом пожалуйста расскажи как всё прошло :3

Comment: @timob256 если переживу, напишу )

Comment: timob256 баллами никто не хвастается, так что вполне можете и со 100 придти, посидеть послушать, или сами что рассказать. Кстати, @Suvitruf, роль модератора встречи берете на себя вы?

Comment: @Kromster я даже не знаю, что это в себя включает)

Comment: Советую вам взять эту роль, на правах зачинщика встречи. Это что-то типа Dungeon Master-а. В большой компании незнакомых людей желателен кто-то, кто будет задавать тон, задаст несколько общих вопросов всем, представит людей друг другу. Ближайшая аналогия - "вы позвали к себе на ДР десяток друзей незнакомых друг с другом" и надо чтобы всем было интересно.

Comment: @Kromster думаю, справлюсь ^^"

Comment: К сожалению, у меня не получится прийти завтра :-( ...меня не будет в городе.

Comment: А вы можете стримить , какие там вопросы будут ??? какие обсуждения ?? Я тогда по интернету посмотрю

Comment: @timob256, не думаю, что кто-то этим будет заморачиваться. Туда люди идут расслабиться, познакомиться, пообщаться. Это же не экзамен и не зачет, чтобы список вопросов и тем был заранее заготовлен...обычное общение,часто может быть не связанное с предметной областью. Обычное живое общение. И по поводу репы я бы не стал комплексовать. Циферка в профиле не значит что кто-то умнее или лучше тебя. И люди приходят явно не для того чтобы циферками мерится. Это  не то сообщество, в котором стоит стесняться своих познаний и каких-то там циферок.  Так что я советую  пойти и хорошо провести свое время.

Comment: Чуть не пропустил встречу! Подскажите, на чьё имя заказан столик? Тем, кто опоздает, надо как-то найти собравшихся в зале.

Comment: @timob256 не думаю, что кто то будет это делать, потому что это геммор. Надеюсь хотя бы фото будут.

Comment: @MarkShevchenko на Андрея Апанасика.

Comment: Можно телефон организатора как-то получить, если поеду завтра может понадобиться. Помню на встречу чата одно пришёл однажды и просто никого не нашёл... Ещё вопрос какой там средний чек?

Comment: На сайте заведения есть меню - можно заранее узнать свой точный чек.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин VK и Телеграм профили приложил к треду.

Comment: @Suvitruf Обычно все собираются очень-очень долго. Если вы будете всех ждать на улице, есть вероятность хорошенько замерзнуть. На мой взгляд, вариант сбора на месте выглядит перспективней =)

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky я планирую до 19:30 +- подождать, потом уже пойти, а остальные уже внутри найдут нас )

Comment: @Suvitruf . с плашками определились?:)

Comment: @Vyacheslav вы про не-робота? Написано же в вопросе, что не будет их

Comment: @AntonSorokin а, сорян, не знал, как это по-русски. А на каких мероприятия в Москве такое могут выдавать?

Comment: @Vyacheslav только если на них есть официальный представитель компании. В случае с SOru, Николас.

Comment: @Vyacheslav на тех, где будет CM, т.е. Nicolas. Он хотел приехать, но не смог(из-за этого мерча тоже не будет). Наверное на следующую встречу в Мск он придет, но пока неизвестно, когда она будет. Из ближайших встреч - в Питере через месяц или 2

Comment: @Suvitruf "_Предлагаю собираться на улице недалеко от входа._" Недалеко от входа куда ? В паб или метро. И если вдруг метро, то какой конкретно выход.

Comment: @Mike снаружи. Обновил пост. Я просто не помню тот район. Если что, то внутри заведения )

Comment: @Suvitruf Понял. Тогда это 1й выход (на яндекс картах начали писать номера выходов и что не маловажно, в самом метро на указателях в коричневом квадратике написан тот же номер)

Comment: уже в баре, поработаю пока с ноутом.

Comment: @Kromster рановато вы, я только с офиса выйду через минут 10)

Comment: @AntonSorokin откуда инфа про СПб? Кстати, в чат бы это всё перекинуть. Где этот чёртов модератор!?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ так еще давным давно, когда только зародилась идея, предлагали сделать встречу в Питере вслед за Мск, примерно в апреле-мае. Да, в чат неплохо. Ну а Николас писал что-то вроде "вот встретимся на встрече в Питере я все расскажу" - поэтому я полагаю, что и встреча будет, и Николас.

Comment: @anatol ещё пара мест

Comment: Привет расскажите как прошло, что делали ?

Comment: Все, кто был, должны были получить знак «не робот». Если у кого–то его еще нет, пожалуйста, напишите мне в чате или тут!

Answer (score 21):

Всем спасибо, было круто! ☺

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Молодцы! Жаль, у меня с работой не сложилось... А сколько человек собралось и кто именно был?

Comment: 11 человек с Николасом. Кто именно был - отмечайтесь в комментариях )

Comment: ....٩(◕‿◕｡)۶...

Comment: Да, Николая на фотке узнал.

Comment: @avp с работой не сложилось или всё таки со встречей? :)

Comment: А говорили без наклеек и наклеивателя. Небось еще и неробота выдавали.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ конечно :P

Comment: Было очень круто!

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, со временем, чтобы  доехать до встречи из Зеленограда  (пока все поправил, его уже не осталось)

Comment: @Suvitruf Блиин, я как-то не слежу за Метой, пропустил... Когда вновь будет встреча в Мск, дайте знать:)

Comment: @Suvitruf says Reinstate Monica где мы тут ? ....٩(◕‿◕｡)۶...

Comment: @Leks крайний справа. В другом ответе все подписаны)

Comment: @Suvitruf says Reinstate если считать с левой стороны на картинке Вы второй ?

Comment: На этой 7-ой, на другой 2-й, да.

Comment: и Suvitruf says Reinstate  тут  такой молодой ... (¬‿¬ )

Answer (score 18):

Большое спасибо всем, кто пришел! Отдельное спасибо организатору [@Suvitruf](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/15479/suvitruf). Было очень приятно познакомиться со всеми лично!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По часовой стрелке:

1. [Дмитрий Полянин](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/205037/%D0%94%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BD).
2. [Suvitruf (aka Андрей)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/15479/suvitruf).
3. [Николас](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/6/nicolas-chabanovsky).
4. [rdorn](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/198316/rdorn).
5. [mymedia](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/183314/mymedia).
6. [Anatol](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/183842/anatol).
7. [Fat-Zer](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/277616/fat-zer)
8. [kromster](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/177188/kromster).
9. [mkkik](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/207200/mkkik)
10. [Mike](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/194569/mike).
11. [yury-bakharev](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/223583/yury-bakharev).

Comment: Если кого-то криво отметил, поправьте, а то у меня память на лица нулевая ^^"

Comment: Скорый поезд к дому мчится... деанонизация...

Comment: @Suvitruf а кто 7ой? Или его нет на SO?

Comment: Класс! Молодцы, что собрались! Жаль, что не смогла. Питер планируется?)

Comment: @kizoso Надеюсь!

Comment: @AntonSorokin я не помню )=

Comment: @Suvitruf судя по выданным знакам не было никакого седьмого

Comment: @αλεχολυτ illuminati confirmed.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ в их ряды затесался иностранный(зачеркнуто) агент с quora?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9IZ4M.png

Comment: @AntonSorokin главное, что не с qaru :)

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Хотел написать qaru(. Постоянно путаю эти 2 сайта.

Comment: А почему у Николаса не-робот? Он же никого из представителей компании не встречал. Хм...

Comment: @AntonSorokin Николас встречал, и неоднократно

Comment: @Kromster утром проснулся, посмотрел в зеркало, что-то на робота не похож ... выдам-ка я себе знак // Я думаю, Anton хотел сказать о том, что КМ получал знаки по сути от себя же, а не от другого сотрудника компании.

Comment: Тогда да, есть нестыковка ))

Comment: если что, то тот таинственный лик, проявившийся на фото в дальним углу принадлежит мне...

Comment: Всем спасибо за встречу. Было классно!
Приятно было познакомиться со всеми! Классно что Николас тоже был. Думаю что надо и дальше устраивать встречи. Следующая в Москве в безалкогольном месте ))

Comment: Кстати 3d наклейка легко превращается в магнит для холодильника, проапгрейдил себе холодильник )) Если кому интересно могу фотку скинуть.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky А тебя про ништяки с enso тут можно спрашивать, ты обещал подробнее рассказать, или в приват лучше?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky мне тоже интересно

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин про магнит, расскажите как? )

Comment: @Kromster Бывают продаются или просто где-то как реклама даются магнитные наклейки, там намагниченая тонкая резина, с рекламой или постером снаружи. Режется под размер наклейки и наклеивается с обратной стороны. У меня на холодильнике много самодельных наклеек. А резинки с магнитами, если где попадаются не выкидываю и они ждут своего часа. Или можно просто купить в сувенирах. В данном случае наклейка самоклеющаяся, а так клеить можно на двухсторонний скотч или клей. Скотчем быстрее и удобнее, и если что можно и отклеить потом.

Comment: И ещё лучше магнитную основу делать сразу на всю поверхность, по возможности, так как резина может слабо магнитить, и если площадь поверхности маленькая может не хватить магнитной силы.

Comment: ИМХО тут самое сложное - аккуратно по контуру обрезать, чтобы прилично смотрелось. Наверно скальпелем или макетным ножём тонким ..

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин  можно!

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Тогда спариваю. Куда писать надо что бы получить классные ништяки с SO?

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин Спасибо за напоминание. Видимо, уже поздно, к сожалению. [Вот тема](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/321399/announcing-our-amazing-2018-stuff-a-way), про которую я говорил.

Comment: @Kromster может лезвием для канцножа?