# Экипировка от SO

Tags: обсуждение, сувениры-stackoverflow

Видел старые вопросы про сувенирные атрибуты и хотелось бы узнать, как получить или приобрести футболку от  RU SO сегодня (не прям сейчас)). Сделать принт самому не кайф)

Comment: А принты самим делать и нельзя. По крайней мере, когда я хотел сделать принты для участников [встречи в Москве](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8861/15479), то мне запретили это делать.

Comment: Связанное: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1831/15479.

Comment: @Suvitruf информация тухловата, не?

Comment: Поэтому я и не закрыл ваш вопрос как дубликат (:

Comment: Ну вот же прям в важном висит способ прямо сейчас что-то выиграть: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9469/178988

Comment: Не повторяйте мою ошибку. Если вы хотите футболку, то позаботьтесь о том, чтобы получить её до того, как перестанете её хотеть.

Comment: @doox911 если у вас есть знакомый(или нет знакомого, но есть деньги) дизайнер, то можете попросить у него нарисовать лого в высоком разрешении а потом заказать майку на любом профильном сайте(профильном по заказу маек с принтами).

Answer (score 9):

Disclaimer: публикую сугубо личное имхо, моё мнение может расходиться с официальным мнением компании Stack Overflow и её представителями.

---

Если я правильно понимаю, сувенирная продукция SO не продаётся, а вручается за те или иные достижения на сайте (например, выиграть какой-нибудь конкурс, объявленный на Мете, или набрать 100К репы), а также при различных встречах сообщества "Stack Overflow на русском" (иногда, вероятно,  такое может даже случиться при личных встречах с менеджером сообщества).

Короче говоря, требуется участие, а не $$$.

Comment: Вот про 100k - не надо... когда в феврале меня вдруг обрадовали, что за 100k призы прямо из Штатов шлют, то не предупредили, что обещанного три года ждут :) - до сих пор ничего и близко не получил, кроме письма - что вам приз положен... От конкурсов на ruSO все по-честному приходило, а вот за 100k - похоже, чисто реклама :)

Comment: @Harry видимо из РФ посылки доходят с большей вероятностью, чем из США.

Comment: @Harry напишите на MSE об этом. Я думаю, так будет правильнее и больше шанс получить какой-то внятный ответ от аффилированных людей, чем здесь в комментах переливать из пустого в порожнее.

Comment: Да ладно, все просто - они уже год не могут найти почтовую фирму, которая будет рассылать их призы. Но побурчать-то хочется :)

Comment: @Harry напишите-напишите. Чтоб не зря всё это было. Может врут всё и за 100к не дают ничего, а все молчат, т.к. думают что их случай единичный. Надо навести порядок и вывести всех на чистую воду.

Comment: Я один раз спросил (e тех, кто письмо прислали. MSE - аббревиатуру не понял...) - в ответ раздраженно ответили, что они переходят с одной почтовой службы на другую, так что они пришлют. Потом. Когда-нибудь. Может быть :) Ну, может, у них идеосинкразия к ru в SO или там к Киеву - что людям зря на больное место наступать?... От @NicolasChabanovsky все доходило вовремя - ну, этим и ограничусь. Будет лишний повод считать американов балаболами :)

Comment: @Harry https://meta.stackexchange.com/ MSE

Comment: А я бы дал возможность пользователям с определенной репутацией (например, более 5000 :D ) возможность скачать флаер в высоком разрешении для печати. Кто захочет - скачает и распечатает. Флаер узнаваем, на мой взгляд.

Comment: Вот комментарий от модератора другого сайта, который также утверждает, что подарки перестали посылать: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333965/firing-mods-and-forced-relicensing-is-stack-exchange-still-interested-in-cooper#comment1090688_333980 `They stopped sending T-shirts, mod hats, or any swag for that matter of fact`